# How to move icons just above on screen keyboard when textfield widget is focused and back to initial position when it is not focused

Tags: flutter, dart

How can i make some widget be just above the keyboard when textfield is focused and back to their original position when the textfield is unfocused? In my code, i'm trying to get the widgets of the footwidget() method to be on screen as just described.

Here is my code:

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
double _offsetY = 0.0;

```
FocusNode _focusNode = FocusNode();
_focusNode.addListener(() {
  setState(() {
    _offsetY = _focusNode.hasFocus ? MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom : 450.0;
  });
});

return Stack(
  children: [
   
    Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            usernamePhoto(),
            SizedBox(
              height: _offsetY,
              child: TextField(
                style: const TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  hintText: "What's going on?",
                ),
                controller: controller,
                focusNode: _focusNode,
                maxLines: null,
                autofocus: true,
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 16),
            Positioned(
              bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom,
              left: 0,
              right: 0,
              child: footWidgets(),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ],
);
```

}

The aim is to also have the textfield having a set height, and scrollable when the user enters text that goes beyond heigh of the textfield.